# Does SWIG_NewPointerObj allocate memory?

Tags: python, swig

I am using SWIG to create a Python library.
I would like to know if calling SWIG_NewPointerObj with own parameter set to SWIG_POINTER_OWN allocates new memory.

Comment: The `SWIG_POINTER_OWN` flag is only about running the destructor.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223327/what-does-the-last-argument-to-swig-newpointerobj-mean

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You say only about running the destructor. But it is also about freeing memory, isn't it?

Comment: I'm not so sure what you mean by memory allocation.  As I understand it the function `SWIG_NewPointerObj` receives a pointer to a C/C++ object that you have created and wraps it in a Python object.  I don't know the internals of the Python interpreter, so I can't say whether creating a Python object has to allocate.  For sure no memory has to be allocated for your C/C++ object because it has to exist already when calling `SWIG_NewPointerObj`.  When you say `SWIG_POINTER_OWN` you tell the interpreter that it is now responsible for cleaning up the memory for the C/C++ object.

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the comments. Yes, Henri Menke, you are right. I had missunderstood the use of this function.